# Rephrase spoken explanation as a formal written instruction

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

I'm currently studying at University of Applied Sciences and my assignment was to rephrase this spoken explanation as a formal written instruction:

> "You shouldn't place objects in front of an air inlet.
>
> And you should
> keep the inlet grille free from obstructions, and clean it regularly.
> If there's damage to the inlet grille, stop the blower immediately.
>
> Foreign bodies entering the duct can cause serious harm, because the
> unit contains precision-engineered parts revolving at speed, so it's
> highly susceptible to damage"

Here's the formal instruction of the text written by me:

> "Objects should not be placed in front of an air inlet.
>
> The inlet grille should be kept free from obstructions and be cleaned
> regularly. Stop the blower immediately in case of damage to the inlet
> grille.
>
> Serious harm can be caused to the foreign bodies being entered the
> duct due to the fact that precision-engineered parts being revolved at
> speed are being contained by the unit making it highly susceptible to
> damage."

Is this grammatically correct and did I use the passive form correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two paragraphs of your answer are correct. But the third is an explanation, not an instruction, so doesn't need as much doing to it. You could say:
Foreign bodies entering the duct can cause serious harm, because the unit contains precision-engineered parts revolving at speed, and is therefore highly susceptible to damage."

Comment: Thank you, sir for your explanation. This helped me a lot! :)